# How are parent-child aggregate relationships managed in Axon Framework

Tags: axon

The Axon documentation [describes how to *create* a child aggregate](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/modeling/aggregate-creation-from-another-aggregate) from a parent, but not how to retrieve it, or delete it (e.g. for cascading deletes)

Does the parent aggregate typically-explicitly, or automatically-internally keep a list of references to the child aggregates?
Would such references be a collection of aggregate IDs, or, to be more object oriented, a collection of actual instance references to the child aggregates?

Another way to pose this question: What is different about child aggregates vs entities in multi-entity aggregates, and what is different about child aggregates vs totally independent aggregates?

I want a cascading delete (containment) model between parent and child, but I want separate concurrent access to the child objects in a very large collection, hence aggregate member entities are not suitable.

Also note [a similar question in the forum](https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/large-aggregatemember-maps-relationships/2491/4): the OP, Jakob describes a model at the end that includes his own table managing references for cascading... do I need that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require the Entities to be separate Aggregates, then you will be required to maintain a reference table from parent to child.

The support Axon provides to create child Aggregates from a parent Aggregate is to ensure the framework uses a single transaction to publish multiple events. By no means does Axon Framework automatically store the relationships for you.

Instead, all of this should be known within the event stream of the Aggregates. With that in mind, combined with Event Sourcing, you can source any form of data within the Aggregates.

To circle back to your cascading delete scenario: I've actually had direct contact with Jakob about the matter. In his case (and potentially yours) we ended up with an `aggregateId-to-childAggregateIds model dedicated to keeping the references. Upon a delete from a parent Aggregate (on any level), this model is referred to, ensuring the right set of children is deleted too. Note that all this is custom code.

Furthermore, this `aggregateId-to-childAggregateIds` model can be regarded as part of your Command Model (granted that you're aiming to apply CQRS). As such, it's purely used to drive decision-making. Where the decision-making, in this case, is deciding on the right children to send delete commands to.

So, to summarize:

- Axon does not keep parent-child relations for you, other than in the contents of the events you publish.
- I'd opt the `aggregateId-to-childAggregateIds` model to **never** store the entire Aggregate instance. You simply don't need all that data for deciding who to delete. The child's Aggregate identifier should suffice.
- Axon's child Aggregate creation support is purely there to use a single transaction towards the event store to publish the parent's change and the creation of a child, while still benefitting from separate instances for increased concurrency. Axon's Aggregate Member support would mark the children as entities under the parent Aggregate Root instead of their own Aggregate instances.